# Testing the existence of a counter fails inexplicably

Tags: conditionals, counters, undefined

**EDIT 3: I accept the answer bellow as it resolve my problem of testing. Weirdly it did not resolve the problem when i call the function from a caption, but it is out of the scope of this question and i will open a new one for answering my specific secondary problem**

I am currently tuning some functions about footnote. I try to implement a mechanism on footnotemark and footnotetext which need to test the existence of a counter with a given name.

**EDIT : a way more simple minimal example is available at the botom of the post !** 
I have wrote this code (simplified)

```
%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final, DIV=12, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, toc=bibliography, open=right, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[greek,english,french]{babel}
\def\frenchtablename{Tableau} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\usepackage{etoc, blindtext}

\rmfamily
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{b}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub*cmr/bx/sc}{}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, style=authoryear, autopunct=false, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,bibencoding=utf8, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline, footsepline,plainfootsepline, plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\usepackage[french,onelanguage,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xintexpr}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[float=false]{scrhack}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale=FR,
  detect-all,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-minimum-digits = 3,
  group-separator={\,},
  number-unit-product={\,},
  group-digits = integer,
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}},
%  tight-spacing=true,
}
\renewcommand*{\dictumauthorformat}[1]{#1}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
\let\oldfootref\footref
\renewcommand{\footref}[1]{\,\oldfootref{#1}}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS END %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% BEGENNING OF THE WORK ON FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%

%%% Counter for making unique ID for the footnotemark and footnotetext without [] %%%%%%
\newcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}

%%%%% Counter for testing in which branch of testing we go  %%%%%%
\newcounter{lalala}

%%%%% WE change the definition of the two function to redefine them  %%%%%%
\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext
\let\oldfootnotemark\footnotemark
%
\makeatletter


%%%%% we use \@ifnextchar to switch between a case with optionnal argument (detection [ ) and a case with no optionnal argument to have two behaviour very different  %%%%%%
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}{\@ifnextchar[\my@OptHyperFootnotetext\my@HyperFootnotetext}

%%%%% part of the command without optionnal argument, it works, no change neededd %%%%
\newcommand{\my@HyperFootnotetext}[1]{%
    \def\myFootnoteTagtext{hfu:\themyHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}%
\oldfootnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtext]{$\uparrow$}~#1}
}

%%%%% define an new footnote with optional argument : the IF never reach the undefined case, the counter "lala" is never incrememented and "BA" is only shown in the text : i have tested diverses formulation \@ifundefined \ifcsname etc etc... %%%%%
\newcommand{\my@OptHyperFootnotetext}[2][plop]{
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextARGU{hfoi:#1}
    \def\mysavee{saved@Href@#1}

    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname\undefined
    AB\thefootnote\theHfootnote
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname
    \oldfootnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}
    \stepcounter{lalala}
    \else 
    \thelalala
    AA\thefootnote\theHfootnote
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname%
    \oldfootnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}%
    \fi
}



%%%%% Same thing for footnotemark %%%%%
\renewcommand{\footnotemark}{\@ifnextchar[\my@OptHyperFootnotemark\my@HyperFootnotemark}%
%%%%% part of the command without optionnal argument, it works, no change needed %%%%
\newcommand{\my@HyperFootnotemark}{%
    \refstepcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}%
    \def\myFootnoteTagtext{hfu:\themyHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}%
    \label{\myFootnoteTagtext}%
\oldfootnotemark%
}

%%%%% define an new footnote with optional argument : the IF never reach the undefined case, the counter "lala" is never incrememented and "BA" is only shown in the text : i have tested diverses formulation \@ifundefined \ifcsname etc etc... %%%%%

\newcommand{\my@OptHyperFootnotemark}[1][plop]{%
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextargu{hfoi:#1}%
    \def\mysave{saved@Href:#1}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname\undefined 
    BB\thefootnote\theHfootnote
    \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
    \oldfootnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \stepcounter{lalala}
    \else
    \thelalala
    BA\thefootnote\theHfootnote
    \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
    \oldfootnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \fi
}
%
\makeatother



%%%%%%% some package %%%%%%%
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%%%%%% begin %%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter


%%%%%% TEST %%%%%%

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}

BLALALALALALALALALALALA
BLALALALALALALALALALALA
BLALALALALALALALALALALA
BLALALALALALALALALALALA
BLALALALALALALALALALALA

%\makeatletter
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \centering
   {
     \begin{floatrow}[1]
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption[Tino]{\label{Tino} The captionnnnnnnnnnnnnnn \footnotemark[truc] The captionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnPart2
 .}}
{\fbox{\def\svgwidth{0.9\textwidth}\import{images/part1/tino/}{tino_maineps.pdf_tex}}}.
     \end{floatrow}
   }
\end{figure}

\footnotetext[truc]{testfootnote}% 

\end{document}
```

It's simple : in the footnotetext and in the footnotemark i test the existence of a counter created with a name that come with the argument.
The idea is to create (of course) the counter if it's undifined (i have deleted these line here as they are commented in my tests).

On this simple test, the counter should have no mean to be defined as there is no "newcounter" BUT, inexplicably, the test go in the "defined" segment. (whether i call the footnotemark or footnotetext first it doesn't change anything -> it fall in both case in the defined segment. I have putted a counter in these segment to test it )

I have tested several variant of the code, with \isundifined or other macro like that, with no success. (edit : i have tested the solution proposed \ifcsname and it doesn't work neither)

I have also checked that a call to classical counter functions (like \value{}) with this name fail (logically), and it's the case.

I don't understand what could be wrong with this code. Any help would be appreciated ;)

eddi : I have included the begenning of the document (diverses package) and a minimal example inside a figure to test it. (it's a pdf_tex, you have to generate an adhoc one with inkscape i guess but i guess the test fails too outside a figure, here the fact that this is a figure seems to not be relevant in the problem). 
I have also commented the code to make it more clear

**EDIT EDIT : NEW MINIMAL EXAMPLE (with ifcsname this time) :**

```
%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final, DIV=12, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, toc=bibliography, open=right, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[greek,english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

%%%%%%%%%%% LOT OF PACKAGES AND DEFINITIONS END %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% BEGENNING OF THE WORK ON FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%

%%% Counter for making unique ID for the footnotemark and footnotetext without [] %%%%%%
\newcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounterMARK}
%%%%% Counter for testing in which branch of testing we go  %%%%%%
\newcounter{lalala}
%
\makeatletter

%%%%% define an new footnote with optional argument : the IF never reach the undefined case, the counter "lala" is never incrememented and "BA" is only shown in the text : i have tested diverses formulation \@ifundefined \ifcsname etc etc... %%%%%
\newcommand{\myOptHyperFootnotetext}[2][plop]{
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextARGU{hfoi:#1}
    \def\mysavee{saved@Href@#1}
    %
    \ifcsname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname
    % CASE UNDEFINED
    AB\stepcounter{lalala}
    %
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname
    \oldfootnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}
    %
    \else 
    % CASE DEFINED
    AA\thelalala
    %
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\Hy@footnote@currentHref\csname\mysavee\endcsname%
    \footnotetext{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTagtextARGU]{$\uparrow$}~#2}%
    %
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\myOptHyperFootnotemark}[1][plop]{%
    \def\myFootnoteTagtextargu{hfoi:#1}%
    \def\mysave{saved@Href:#1}%
    %
    \ifcsname c@counter@Href:#1\endcsname
    % CASE UNDEFINED
    BB\stepcounter{lalala}
    \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
    %
    \oldfootnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    %
    \else   
    % CASE DEFINED
    BA\thelalala
    %
    \label{\myFootnoteTagtextargu}
    \footnotemark \global\expandafter\let\csname\mysave\endcsname\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \fi
}
%
\makeatother



%%%%%%% some package %%%%%%%
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

%%%%%% begin %%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter


%%%%%% TEST %%%%%%

\chapter{TEST}
\section{Introduction}

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

\myOptHyperFootnotemark[truc]

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

\myOptHyperFootnotetext[truc]{testfootnote}% 

\end{document}
```

This code give : 
[image: minimalresult]

The BA and AA on the result show that the undefined bloc is never called. The 0 after BA and AA is the counter Lala which ensure that at this point the undefined bloc was never called.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. That's quite a bit of code. Could you please make it compilable by putting it into a complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There are obvious mistakes such as the backslash in `\stepcounter{\lalala}`.  It should be `\stepcounter{lalala}`. Maybe it is better going in smaller steps.

Comment: @AlanMunn : i have edited the post to give a minimal example at the bottom of the post, the minimal example is compilable and i have put an image for the result

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat : i have changed the lalala counter in the new minimal example, it didn't change the problem, the counter is still outputing 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test either with `\ifcsname` or with `\@ifundefined`. Be aware that using an undefined \csname sets it to `\relax` and that the two tests handles this differently:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter 

\ifcsname c@counter@Href:XXX\endcsname
 defined \else undefined \fi


 \@ifundefined{c@counter@Href:XXX}
  {undefined}{defined}


\csname c@counter@Href:XXX\endcsname %sets it to \relax

\ifcsname c@counter@Href:XXX\endcsname
 defined \else undefined \fi


 \@ifundefined{c@counter@Href:XXX}
  {undefined}{defined}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but i have also tested with \@ifundefined with no success. Other comment on \@ifundefined seems to say that this defined the undefined as well with a relax in its definition....
I will try ifcsname but it was my initial solution with no luck ...

Comment: No \@ifundefined doesn't define the command, at least not in a current latex, that was changed some years ago.

Comment: Beside this: I have neither the time nor the will to try to extend your snippets to build a test document.

Comment: Hum, i will try to make a more minimal example ...

Comment: I have made a new minimal example at the bottom of the code, it is wayyyy smaller and reproduce the problem with your ifcsname :)

Comment: Should one also test the catcode?  While all counters use the c@ naming protocol, one could always create a macro with such a name.

Comment: well if the comments mean what they say you have the wrong order of the branches. \ifcsname is true is the csname is defined.

Comment: Ok, i have corrected the order of ifcsname (stupid error) and made further testing with the minimal example.
It appears that it works and give the result ... but not in the first case (complex code). I have trying to figure out why and very weirdy it seems that calling a "newcounter" in the undefined part of the two function (classic conditional assignation) works ..... as long as the function are not called within a figure...
When the function are called within a figure, it's like the counter is automagicaly defined before but without calling the rest of the function ... very strange...

Comment: (rest of my last comment) but i guess this specific problem is a bit too far from the original on this topic, may be i should close this one with the answer code that work outside of figure environnement and open a new subject for the second part of the problem ?

Comment: @JohnKormylo How would you test the catcode in this case ?

Comment: Beats the heck out of me.  I've been playing with \ifcat\c@test\c@page and variations and have found no test that yields a negative result for a macro and a positive result for a counter.  The information exists, since \meaning can tell the difference.  The best I've come up with is to test both c@test and thetest, since \newcounter will create both.

Comment: @JohnKormylo i have tested it, may be this should help the problem i have with it when called in figure. But in fact no.
Though i keep the idea of testing c@ and thetest, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that if `\meaning` can tell the difference between a counter and a macro, one could simply test the output of `\meaning`.  That turned out to be more difficult than I anticipated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testcounter}[1]% name
{\bgroup
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{not defined}{defined} -
  \StrCompare{\expandafter\meaning\csname c@#1\endcsname}{\meaning\c@page}[\pos]%
  \ifnum\pos=7
    counter
  \else
    \ifnum\pos=0
      page counter
    \else
      not a counter
    \fi
  \fi
\egroup\par}

\def\c@test{test}% fake counter
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo: \testcounter{foo}

figure: \testcounter{figure}

page: \testcounter{page}

test: \testcounter{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the precision ! 
Have you a specific idea for the inside of a caption ? 
I have noticed that if the function are called from the inside of a caption, the function are called twice, which is awfull when it come to conditionnal assignement/testing ...

Comment: This was intended as a demonstration of principle, not a working macro.  I really don't get where you are going with this, but it seemed like an interesting problem.  As for captions, IIRC something sets `\let\label=\@gobble` in the TOC, besides one can always use the optional [short caption].  You will also note that the `\meaning` test works even when the name is undefined, so you can skip the `\@ifundefined` test.